# Disable workspace switch when opening a new window of a program already opened in another workspace

Tags: macos, spaces

When I want to open a new window of a program already opened in another workspace the opened window gets automatically focused in the other workspace. Thats annoying because I always have to get back to the previous workspace and use the context menu in Dock to force a new window. How is it possible to turn that off? I am using OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by turning off the "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application" checkbox in Mission Control preferences.

However, this will mean that when you toggle to a different application, with Cmd+Tab or another mechanism, you'll stay in the same workspace. This may or many not be convenient for your workflow.

Comment: I found that option too and unticket it. But now when I click on a program in Dock nothing happens at first. When I click again the other workspace slides in, as before.

Answer (score 2):

*You can do this by turning off the "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application" checkbox in Mission Control preferences.*

This option does next to nothing. Mission Control still switches workspaces when switching applications, closing windows, opening windows, etc. As far as I can tell, the only thing this option has any effect on whatsoever is Chrome. When I click on Chrome in the dock with a window open elsewhere, it does not switch and gives me a chance to open a new window. (However, if I make the mistake of clicking twice, I get banished from whatever it was I was working on).

Is there any way to disable auto-switching entirely? I NEVER want to be moved to a new workspace against my will. I can't imagine this is a pleasant experience for anyone.

Thanks.